# send multiple parameter using ajax and save data into database

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

> send multiple parameter using ajax and save data into database....and in the case of packet i want value will remain unchange on form mean i don't want that my form reload so, how it is possible i'm a newbie please give your valuable suggestions
>
> onsubmitbtn call on submit button

```
function onsubmitbtn(){
    var packet = document.getElementById("packet").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var sub = document.getElementById("sub").value;
    var zipcode = document.getElementById("zcode").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var data = "packet=" +packet+ "&name="+name+ "&number="+number+ "&sub="+sub+ "&zipcode="+zipcode+ "&city="+city+ "&weight="+weight;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var response = request.responseText;
        }
        request.open("get", "PickUpInvertFormSubmit.jsp?"+data, true);
        request.send();          
}
```

> i want to send multiple parameters in my ajax and save the value in my database. if the packet is more than one in that case i want that on submit but the value in input field will remain same
>
> jsp code for insert data into database

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String[] splt = client.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("\\|");

    String number = request.getParameter("number");
    String sub = request.getParameter("sub");
    String zip = request.getParameter("zipcode");
    int z = Integer.valueOf(zip);
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String pkt = request.getParameter("packet");
    int p = Integer.valueOf(pcs);
    String weight = request.getParameter("weight");
    double w = Double.valueOf(weight);
    Dbcon dbc = new Dbcon();
    Connection con = dbc.ConnDb();
        String query = "insert query"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
        PreparedStatement psmt = null;

        try {
            psmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            psmt.setString(1, ....);
            psmt.setString(2, .......);
            psmt.setString(3, ........);
            psmt.setInt(4, .......);
            psmt.setString(5, .......);
            psmt.setInt(6, ..........);
            psmt.setDouble(7, .......);

            psmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dbc.disconnect(null, null, null, psmt);
        }
    }
```

> this code works perfectly when i use this code on action
>
> onsubmit button event my form field get refreshed and no data save in database...

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but `"PickUpInvertFormSubmit.jsp?data="+data` should be `"PickUpInvertFormSubmit.jsp?"+data`

Comment: @JoshuaK  i try this but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function onsubmitbtn() {
    var packet = document.getElementById("packet").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var sub = document.getElementById("sub").value;
    var zipcode = document.getElementById("zcode").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            url: "PickUpInvertFormSubmit.jsp", 
                            data: {
                                "packet": packet,
                                "name": name,
                                "number": number,
                                "sub": sub,
                                "zipcode": zipcode,
                                "city": city,
                                "weight": weight
                            },
                            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                successMethod(data);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                errorMethod(errorThrown);
                            }
                        });
}
```

Your data can't be altered after submission and also can't be bookmarked.

you can also use `alert("success: " + data);` in `success` value of `ajax` function and same in `error` of the ajax method.

Using this, data is not appended to browser's URL and you don't have to modify your controller/jsp.

This method will make a call to URL in background and you can perform cleanup in the success method.

also import jQuery in head tag of your document as

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can download jQuery from here [Download jQuery | jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/)

Hope this helps :)